# How to override a vendor Bundle Configuration?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use JMSSerializerBundle, I installed it with Composer.

I generated my OwnBundle with the symfony generator, and I'm able to use `$this->get('serializer')`

However, I'd like to override configuration as it is stated in the documentation, so I created a config.yml in `My/OwnBundle/Resources/config/` and I put

```
  jms_serializer:
    metadata:
      directories:
        OwnBundle:
          namespace_prefix: My\OwnBundle
          path: %kernel.root_dir%/serializer/
```

To make sure my config is loaded, I added

```
$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('services.yml');
$loader->load('config.yml');
```

But I got this error when running console tool:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "jms_serializer" (in
>   ~/My/OwnBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml).
>   Looked for namespace "jms_serializer", found none

Am I doing something wrong?

For informations, my services.yml is empty (empty services & parameters).

I'm totally new to Symfony2, but I RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to register the JMSSerializer namespace in autoload.php? Check that file to see if it is there.